# A word for series of unintentional events that lead up to a blunder?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Unintentional or human error all coming together to cause an unfortunate incident?

What's a good word that best describes this?

Comment: Lemony Snicket-esque ? Or, Lemony Snicket-iesque ?

Answer (score 3):

A favourite of mine that is popular in Britain is **omnishambles**.

The OED defines an omnishambles as:

> A situation that has been comprehensively mismanaged, characterized by a string of blunders and miscalculations:

Answer (score 2):

I think it is overused in the extreme, but the current favorite expression seems to be [*the perfect storm*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=define+%22the+perfect+storm%22&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&start=0):

> a particularly bad or critical state of affairs, arising from a number of negative and unpredictable factors: "the past two years have been a perfect storm for the travel industry"

It is used (erroneously) for such uncritical events as the setting for embezzlement:

> "According to the criminal complaint, Maritz Jr. told police, 'It was the perfect storm. People trusted me and I took advantage of the trust they had in me.'"

The term has been around for centuries, but was made popular in culture by a book describing the events leading up to the 1991 Nor'easter that claimed the lives of the fishermen aboard the *Andrea Gail*:

> the confluence of three different weather-related phenomena that combined to create what (meteorologist) Case referred to as the "perfect situation" to generate such a (rare and dangerous) storm...

in culture:

> It was the *perfect storm* of a bad economy, a bad job market, and the decline of the long-standing business model of the music business.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal [missteps](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misstep) :

> - an unintentional but embarrassing blunder.

(TFD)

Comment: that's not cited in TFD as far as I could tell. Instead it says: *an unintentional but embarrassing blunder* And *misstep* is used more commonly in the singular. Perhaps the phrase [**a series of mishaps**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/mishap) conveys the idea more clearly. But that's no longer a single word.

Comment: Yes sorry, I  mixed it up.